# How can I troubleshoot Azure ARM template validation errors?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have made some small changes to an Azure ARM template file and now when I try to deploy or validate via the xplat cli I get this message.

> error:   InvalidTemplateDeployment : The template deployment
>   'fakedDeploymentName' is not valid according to the validation
>   procedure. The tracking id is '\some kind of GUID here\'.
>   See inner errors for details. Please see http://aka.ms/arm-deploy for
>   usage details.
>
> error:   PreflightValidationCheckFailed : Preflight
>   validation failed. Please refer to the details for the specific
>   errors.

I would love to troubleshoot this problem, but I don't see any "inner errors" on the console. It even gives me a unique GUID each time, implying that I could use this GUID to look up a more informative message. Where can I view a more detailed error? (not looking for help on the real source of the error yet)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Make sure you're running the latest version of the CLI, we're working on bubbling up the detailed error.  If that's still not catching it, let us know https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/issues

Then if the log isn't showing you the detail, run the deployment with the -vv switch, the detailed debug output (while verbose) will have all the error messages and you can usually sift through and find the specific failure.

```
azure group deployment create ... --debug
```

Powershell:

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment ... -debug
```

Comment: When using `New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment`, the equivalent would be `-Debug`. I think. (at least, it helped me)

Comment: for others that ended up on this page like me, for the az cli the switch is not -vv but --debug.

Answer (score 65):

Log into the azure portal portal.azure.com.

Open the Activity log

Find the record with Operation Name of Validate in the list of activities.  It should have a red exclamation mark because it failed.

Click on it that record.  Then click on the JSON tab at the bottom.  Get reading and somewhere deep down in returned Json you might find an error in the statusMessage such as "The storage account named helloworld is already taken."

Comment: How can that be done with c#? it would be good to validate the JSON for things like missing parameters/values (catch typos, etc).

Comment: In my case Activity log didn't have the error (some maintenance there?) but `-Debug` as in other answer helped.

Comment: Thanks! This should be the accepted answer, this is the only thing that helped me.

Comment: Thanks! I did this and I found out why I could not add a new Azure Function - "The requested app service plan cannot be created in the current resource group because it is hosting Linux apps. Please choose a different resource group or create a new one."

Comment: This is the only thing that helped me. Tried the accepted answer as well but no help. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 20):

### Updated (Feb 2024)

Use `Get-AzLog` as `Get-AzureRMLog` is now deprecated.

`Get-AzLog -CorrelationId xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -DetailedOutput`

---

### Orignal answer (Nov 2016)

Run the following PowerShell Azure cmdlet with the tracking ID supplied:

`Get-AzureRMLog -CorrelationId xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -DetailedOutput`

Comment: This worked for me, the inner exception provided the details I needed to troubleshoot my issue.

Comment: To make it faster/easier to find the error issue I used `grep` and `less` with a variable as follows: `$correlationId='xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'` then the command `Get-AzureRmLog -CorrelationId $correlationID -DetailedOutput  | grep -C 10 $correlationID | less`

Answer (score 2):

I believe that tracking ID is for technical support for looking at their logs, not for the user.
Regarding your exact question, you need to take a look at logs - [reference](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-manager-troubleshoot-deployments-cli/).

Another good way to validate the template is to use [Resource Explorer](http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2015/11/22/creating-arm-templates-with-azure-resource-explorer.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Building on nftw's answer...

To make it faster/easier to find the error issue I used `grep` and `less` with a variable as follows:

```
$correlationId ='xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' # store your correlation ID here
Get-AzureRmLog -CorrelationId $correlationID -DetailedOutput | grep -C 10 $correlationID | less
```

In my testing the error was close to the top of the output. You could use `less` and the forward-slash key <kbd>/</kbd> and search "error" to find the error even quicker.

Comment: grep didn't work but the detailed error is in ```Properties``` thanks

Answer (score 1):

Building on @nftw:

```
$deploymentGroupName = 'deploymentGroupName'
$correlationId = ((Get-AzureRMLog -ResourceGroup $deploymentGroupName)[0]).CorrelationId
$logentry = (Get-AzureRMLog -CorrelationId $correlationId -DetailedOutput)
#$logentry
$rawStatusMessage = $logentry.Properties
$status = $rawStatusMessage.Content.statusMessage | ConvertFrom-Json
$status.error.details
$status.error.details.details
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running in the same issue. Basically, I couldn't get any details passed "InvalidTemplateDeployment".

I added my ARM template in a Visual Studio: Azure Resource Group project template and tried to deploy it. I got verbose details in the Output tab. That helped me solve my problem.

In my case it was the name of the cluster, it can only be small letters and numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
az vm list [--only-show-errors]
           [--resource-group]
           [--show-details]
           [--subscription]
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Az module in PowerShell you can use `Get-AzLog` in place of `Get-AzureRMLog` (based on the answer by @nftw):

```
Get-AzLog -CorrelationId 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx' -DetailedOutput
```